# Qt: default connection timeout for QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qtnetwork, qtcpsocket

Please advise how can I setup default connection timeout without using blocking waitForConnected() method? I noticed that socket emit error signal (QAbstractSocket::SocketTimeoutError) after about 60 seconds that I can handle as a timeout, but can this timeout be adjusted?

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is other solution. You can adjust waitForConnected() but if you don't want this function to be blocking (probably because of GUI or anything), you should use a thread.

Comment: Exactly, because of GUI blocking. I want to have persistent connection  for the socket, but I don't know how to do it with threads. If I just move to thread waitForConnected() call, it shows me an output in console 'Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different Thread', but there is no any explicit object creation, just singe waitForConnected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html):

- Start it after you have called [`connectToHost`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost).
- You may want to reset the timer when socket state changes from [`QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState` to `QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketState-enum), perhaps with different timeout, if you want more fine-grained control on when exactly will the timeout happen.
- If you get connection, stop the timer, or reset it for similar send/receive timeout use.
- If you get timer timeout, do [`disconnectFromHost()`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#disconnectFromHost) and possibly do something like retry when you get disconnect signal.

When developing, make sure to connect the [`stateChanged(...)`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#stateChanged) and [`error(...)`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-2) signals at least to debug slots, which just print the arguments. That way you will see when something happens in a way you did not expect.

Comment: yes, now I implemented it like this with startTimer() of QObject. So I can accept this answer for now.